# Connected to Ethernet but no Internet access

Tags: macos, network, wifi, dns, ethernet

I am having a very frustrating problem. My 2009 iMac is connected to our network by Ethernet, however it cannot access the Internet.

All my other devices work fine, and local adresses (192.168.0.1 for example) work fine. Things I have tried so far:

- Restarting Router and iMac
- Connected to a different network, same results
- Changed DNS, flushed DNS-Cache and tried to open IP's directly in Chrome
- Removed Network completely, deleting "SystemPreferences" Folder

Pinging IP's in Terminal results in timeouts, pinging hosts in "cannot resolve: Unknown Host".

At this point I have spent several days of searching through forums and trying everything I can think of.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: When you say you've connected to a different network, how was that done?  Did you use the same ethernet cable for that connection? Can you connect to any other network resources (like servers, printers, etc) or is it just going out to the internet?

Comment: Deleting SystemPreferences can leave things in a weird state; make sure you reboot afterward, and then create a new network location in System Preferences. If that doesn't get it working, more info will be needed: is it getting a valid IP address for the local network? Are the subnet mask, router, and DNS server(s) the same as other devices on the same net that are working (I assume there are some)?

Comment: I have connected to a hotspot on my phone, and a local community hotspot by Wi-Fi, but with the same results. I haven't tried accessing Printers, however pinging DNS-Servers such as 1.1.1.1 directly is working!

Comment: I haven't tried manually adding a new network location, but I made sure to reboot. The iMac is getting a valid IP-Adress, I already tried it with a static one. Subnet mask and Router seem to be correct, and I have already tried all DNS-Servers i can think of, including of course the standard ISP one.